# Run two instances of JBoss Fuse on the same box

Tags: jbossfuse

What configuration files/values to change in order to run second instance of the JBoss Fuse on the same box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Second instance properties after configuration:

```
Installation home: c:\jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084-2 (/usr/app/jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084-2)
Remote debug port: 5006
Jetty/CXF port: 8282
RMI registry port: 2099
RMI server port: 54444
SSH port: 8202
ActiveMQ port: 62616
HawtIO console: http://localhost:8282/hawtio/login
```

### Installation home:

```
$JBOSS_FUSE_HOME\bin\setenv
----
KARAF_HOME=/usr/app/jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084-2
KARAF_DATA=/usr/app/jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084-2/data
KARAF_ETC=/usr/app/jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084-2/etc
export KARAF_HOME
export KARAF_DATA
export KARAF_ETC

%JBOSS_FUSE_HOME%\bin\setenv.bat
----
SET KARAF_HOME=c:\jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084-2
SET KARAF_DATA=c:\jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084-2\data
SET KARAF_ETC=c:\jboss-fuse-6.2.1.redhat-084-2\etc
```

### Remote debug port

```
$JBOSS_FUSE_HOME\bin\admin
$JBOSS_FUSE_HOME\bin\karaf
$JBOSS_FUSE_HOME\bin\patch
----
DEFAULT_JAVA_DEBUG_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5006" 

%JBOSS_FUSE_HOME%\bin\admin.bat
%JBOSS_FUSE_HOME%\bin\karaf.bat
%JBOSS_FUSE_HOME%\bin\patch.bat
----
set DEFAULT_JAVA_DEBUG_OPTS=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5006
```

### Jetty/CXF port

```
JBOSS_FUSE_HOME\etc\jetty.xml
---
<Property name="jetty.port" default="8282"/>

JBOSS_FUSE_HOME\etc\org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg
---
org.osgi.service.http.port=8282

JBOSS_FUSE_HOME\etc\system.properties
---
org.osgi.service.http.port=8282
```

### RMI registry port/RMI server port

```
JBOSS_FUSE_HOME\etc\org.apache.karaf.management.cfg
---
rmiRegistryPort = 2099
rmiServerPort = 54444
```

### SSH port

```
JBOSS_FUSE_HOME\etc\org.apache.karaf.shell.cfg
---
sshPort = 8202
```

### ActiveMQ port

```
JBOSS_FUSE_HOME\etc\system.properties
---
activemq.port = 62616
activemq.host = localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the applications installed, so let's stick with vanilla JBoss Fuse 6.2+
There are 3 components that need a change in configuration:

- ActiveMQ broker
- Hawtio web interface
- sshd

Conflicts happen while binding on TCP/IP ports. Use two sets of ports and you're done.

---

Configuration files are located in `$KARAF_ETC` folder, usually `etc/` inside JBoss Fuse installation folder.

## ActiveMQ

Change property `activemq.port` inside `etc/system.properties`.
Default value is 61616.

## Hawtio / OSGi HTTP

Change property `org.osgi.service.http.port` inside `etc/system.properties`. Default is 8181.
This is also defined in `etc/org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg`.

## SSH

Change property `sshPort` inside `etc/org.apache.karaf.shell.cfg`. Default is 8101

Answer (score 0):

Another way: Create a `Fabric` with two `child containers`. Each container is just like a regular instance. The infrastructure is just a bit more complex than the standalone one.